# downloading file error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I wrote a program to download files from a website by using `WebClient.DownloadFile()`.

```
public static void downWeb()
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }              
    if (add() == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response is " + add());           
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading File = " + dynFileName + "....");
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(fullAddress, (path + dynFileName));
    }
}

public static int add()
{
    string url = fullAddress;

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse webResponse;
    try
    {
        webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

`downWeb()` is a function to be called in the `Main()` function.

`add()` is a function that tests the availability of the file on server. If response is positive, it returns value "1".

fullAddress = address from where the files has to downloaded. It's changing every time before calling this function in a loop present in `Main()`.

When I start my application, I ask the user to:

1) Enter URL to be downloaded i.e. www.1234.com\samplefiles\pg-1.pdf

2) Number of pages to be downloaded (By changing the above filename no. in a loop as rest of the url is same on server)

Now my problem is when I am downloading files, first file downloads PERFECTLY, but the second download is never finished. It says "REQUEST TIMED OUT", and my application closes.

I don't know what's happening here.

How can this be solved?

Comment: What behaviour do you see when setting a breakpoint on the important events?

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

> You must call the Close method to close the stream and release the connection. Failure to do so may cause your application to run out of connections.

Your problem likely is related to the fact that you do not dispose of your connections. You should make sure that you don't leak them.